# Is there a way to use GNOME Evolution as a way to sync a Maildir, like offlineimap or isync/mbsync?

Tags: gnome, email, evolution

I noticed that Evolution stores its mail in a maildir now. Is there a way to sync my mail to that maildir, so that I can read it with a program like mu4e?

I use Arch, BTW.